# How to perform blockchain transaction (mint) through backend

Tags: blockchain, wallets, polygon, mint, api

I am trying to create an API which can perform POST on Blockchain node. But I need a way to complete the minting of the transaction without using UI.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Hardhat tasks/scripts. Basically you just need a script connected to an .env file where is the private key and you can perform POST on blockchain.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of tech stack are you going to use?

Ethereum support `RPC` calls per [docs](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/). Market offers variety of libraries for different tech stacks to work with a chain. [Here is one](https://github.com/web3j/web3j) for `Enterpise Java\Kotlin\Android`

In case of `web3j` it would implement a `java\kotlin` wrapper around your smart contract where you can execute a `mint()` call.

```
     override fun safeMint(to: String, value: Value, uri: String): RemoteFunctionCall<TransactionReceipt> {
        val function: Function = Function(
            ISwapValue.Functions.FUNC_SAFE_MINT,
            listOf(
                Address(to),
                value,
                Utf8String(uri)),
            Collections.emptyList()
        )
        return executeRemoteCallTransaction(function)
    }
```